# Connect to Redshift via SSL using R

Tags: r, amazon-redshift

I'm currently trying to connect to a redshift database in R. This needs to be done over an SSL connection but I can't seem to find options to specify the path of the certificate file to use in `dbConnect`. Google hasn't been to helpful either surprisingly enough.

Is it really that difficult establish a postgres SSL connection to redshift  via R or am I just missing out on something fundamental?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simply do:

```
host = 'redshift-name.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'
dbname = 'your_db_name'
port = 3306
password = 'hunter2'
username = 'rs_user'
redshift_cert = paste0(FILE_PATH, 'redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem')
pg_dsn = paste0(
    'dbname=', dbname, ' ',
    'sslrootcert=', redshift_cert, ' ',
    'sslmode=verify-full'
)
dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), dbname=pg_dsn, host=host, port=port, password=password, user=username)
```

Comment: What does cacert variable mean here? Is is a string which gives the location of redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem ? is it the contents of redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem ?? Lost!!

Comment: @hibernado check my new edit. Yes it must be the filename of your copy of the redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem file

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `host = 'redshift-name.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'`? Otherwise your host is not define.

Comment: @Boxuan yep [padding]