# Connect to Postgres via SSL using R

Tags: r, postgresql, ssl

I have the same question that was asked here [Connect to Redshift via SSL using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482913/connect-to-redshift-via-ssl-using-r/30987389#30987389)

However, the answer given requires certificate validation. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without certificate validation? When I connect via a sql client, I just add this

```
?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

How can I add these parameters in R?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of passing `verify-full` to `sslmode`, try `require` or `allow`:

```
dbConnect(dbDriver('PostgreSQL'),
    dbname   = 'dbname=foobar sslmode=require',
    host     = 'foobar.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    port     = 5439,
    user     = 'foobar',
    password = 'foobar')
```

Comment: adding the sslmode=require to the dbname causes crah of Rstudio for me

Comment: This didn't work for me neither, but @chrowe's solution did

Comment: I attempted this solution with drv argument as above `dbDriver('PostgreSQL')` and as `RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()` in both cases I got the following error: `Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect <user>@<host>:<port> on dbname "<dbname>": sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in`

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres seems to be the more modern and maintained package at this point. This is what worked for me...

```
install.packages("RPostgres")
require(RPostgres)

db = dbConnect(
  Postgres(), 
  user = 'user',
  password = 'password',
  dbname = 'dbname',
  host = 'host',
  port = port,
  sslmode = 'require'
)

dbListTables(db)
```

Comment: This gave me and my colleague the error `SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer`, until we upgraded `RPostgres` to version `1.2.0` (which was only available using the compile-from-source option and not the binary) and then it worked.

Comment: Can verify that the `sslmode` works for me using `RPostgres` v`1.2.0`.

Comment: Perfect solution, THANK YOU!

Comment: update: RPostgres v1.3.1 returns the same `sslmode='require'` error due to a bug in the release. See https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres/issues/291

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
connection <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                             dbname = "dbname",
                             host = "host",
                             port = "port",
                             password = "password",
                             user = "user_name",
                             base::list(sslmode="require", connect_timeout="10"),
                             service = NULL)
```

So the [parameter key words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) can be passed as a list.
This worked for RPostgres 1.1.1 and 1.2.0, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I rely on R DBI and odbc packages. Here is setup I used with help from @[Floris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3817017/floris)

- First, create client SSL certificate and key, sign client certificate using postgres server root certificate, and also keep postgres server root certificate on client side at `~/.postgresql/`. A client ssl key is owned and read-only by owner only. Here is [a guide from jealastic.com](https://jelastic.com/blog/establish-secure-ssl-connection-to-postgresql-database-server/) that I followed to create server and client SSL certificates.

`ls -alh ~/.postgresql/`

```
drwx------  2 foo staff      122 Jul 23 10:45 ./
drwx------ 54 foo staff 2.1K Jul 23 10:45 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 foo staff      875 Jul 21 17:42 postgresql.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 foo staff      631 Jul 21 17:41 postgresql.csr
-r--------  1 foo staff      891 Jul 21 17:41 postgresql.key
-rw-r--r--  1 foo staff     1.1K Jul 21 17:40 root.crt
```

- `nano ~/.odbcinst.ini` and add following:

```
[PostgreSQL Driver]
Driver              = /home/foo/anaconda3/envs/sql/lib/psqlodbcw.so
```

> where odbc driver was installed in a conda env using `conda create --name sql -c conda-forge psqlodbc`.

- `nano ~/.odbc.ini` and add one or more entry for database you like to connect with valid credentials:

```
[foodb]
Driver              = PostgreSQL Driver
Database            = foodb
Servername          = db.example.com
UserName            = foo
Password            = mypassword
Port                = 5432
sslmode             = require
```

> Note that *PostgreSQL Driver* matches corresponding entry in ~/.odbcinst.ini
>   For type of *sslmode* vs security and overhead, here is a good read: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/libpq-ssl.html

- Fix permissions

```sh
chmod 600 ~/.odbc.ini ~/.odbcinst.ini
```

- In RStudio GUI, either create a new connection and it should show an entry *foodb* from ~/.odbc.ini or type this into R console.

```r
library(odbc)
foodb <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "foodb", timeout = 10)
```

Done!