# RStudio on Windows PostgreSQL SSL Connection with RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, ssl

I am having trouble creating an SSL connection using RPostgreSQL to an AWS hosted PostgreSQL database.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Created the PostgreSQL database on AWS.
2. Set the database parameter "rds.force_ssl" to 1.
3. Downloaded the AWS public key from  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
4. Test the connection from a windows command prompt with psql (it works).
5. Executed the following in R:

   ```
   library(RPostgreSQL)
   cert <- paste0("C:/Users/johnr/Downloads/", "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
   dbname <- paste0("dbname=", "flargnog", " ", "sslrootcert=", cert, " ", "sslmode=verify-full")
   host <- "xxxxxx.xxxxx.us-region-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
   con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), user="username", host=host, port=5432, dbname=dbname, password="abcd1234!")
   ```

I receive an error message after executing the last statement:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not connect username@xxxxxx.xxxxx.us-region-2.rds.amazonaws.com on dbname "flargnog"
```

If I change the rds.force_ssl setting to 0 (and remove the ssl stuff from dbname) the connection works just fine.

I have looked at other posts on Stackoverflow related to this issue.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244210/cant-create-dbconnect-to-postgres-with-ssl) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942118/can-not-connect-postgresqlover-ssl-with-rpostgresql-on-windows) seem to indicate an SSL connection is not possible due to issues with RPostgreSQL.  However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482913/connect-to-redshift-via-ssl-using-r/30987389#30987389) indicates that you can.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to ssh to the rds instance using e.g. putty and port-forward your  local port 5432 to the remote port 5432. Once the ssh connection is open in R just connect to `localhost:5432`...

Here is how to port-forward using putty:
http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html

Here is how this works via command-line:
https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/3d239b82265398568f31

P.S.: Make sure your instance is in a security-group that accepts ssh connections - port 22