# R connection to postgresql requiring SSL

Tags: r, postgresql, ssl

I'm trying to connect R to a postgresql database that requires SSL.

Here's the connection string that works for me when using PSQL:
`postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME:PORT/DBNAME?ssl=true`, replacing all the uppercase strings with appropriate values.

In R, I don't know how to handle the SSL parameter.  When I try 
`conn = dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), host="HOST", dbname="DBNAME", user="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD", port=PORT)`

I get

`Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect USERNAME@HOST on dbname "DBNAME"
)`

When I try `conn = dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), host="HOST", dbname="DBNAME", user="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD", port=PORT, ssl=TRUE)`

I get

`Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : unused argument (ssl = TRUE)`

[Connect to Postgres via SSL using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989264/connect-to-postgres-via-ssl-using-r) suggests adding extra info to the dbname parameter.  I've tried `dbname="DBNAME ssl=TRUE"` which results in `RS-DBI driver: (could not connect (null)@HOST on dbname "(null)"`  I get the same result with `sslmode=allow` and `sslmode=require` (as suggested by the above post).

The documentation for the PostgreSQL driver says, under "User Authentication", "The passed string can be empty to use all default parameters, or it can contain one or more parameter settings separated by comma. Each parameter setting is in the form parameter = "value". Spaces around the equal sign are optional."  But I haven't been able to get it to accept any parameters other than the three shown in the function prototype.

I'm out of ideas;  help appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I didn't.  I ended up writing a query that extracted all the data I needed into a CSV.  Sucked that into R Studio and went from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

1. Create a configuration file like "configuration.yml" and add your setup :

   `db:
    host : "your_localhost"
    dbname : "your_database_name?ssl=true"
    user : "your_user_name"
    port : 5432
    password : "your_password"`
2. Install this packages :

   `install.packages(yaml, dependencies = TRUE)
   install.package(RPostgreSQL, dependencies = TRUE)
   install.packages(DBI, dependencies = TRUE)`
3. Run :

   `driver <- DBI:::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
   con <- do.call( RPostgreSQL:::dbConnect, 
                   c(drv = driver, yaml:::yaml.load_file("configuration.yml")$db)
                  )`
4. /!\  Note /!\  : don't forget to add this statement

   `*?ssl=true*`

   on the configuration.yml file on the dbname field.

Hope this help !