# Establish SSL Connection in R

Tags: r, postgresql

I am trying to create an SSL Connection in RStudio but receiving an error message "sslmode value "verify-ca" invalid when SSL support is not compiled".

I have tried using sslmode = 'require' also but still facing same issues.

Below is the code that I have run at my end

```
pg_dsn = paste(
  'dbname=', dbname, ' ',
  'sslrootcert=', cert_pem_path, ' ',
  'sslmode=verify-ca',
  sep=""
)
## Contains path of the certificate file located at my end

con_posgresql <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = pg_dsn , host = <host> , port = <port>,  user = <username>, password = <password>)
```

I am using RPostgreSQL & DBI library and version of this 2 libraries are RPostgreSQL == 0.6.2, DBI == 1.1.0.

Is there any way I can establish a SSL connection?

I have referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928886/how-to-connect-to-remote-postgresql-with-r-certificate-validation-required) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519231/r-connection-to-postgresql-requiring-ssl) but still facing the same issue.

Kindly help me on this issue.

Comment: What is your OS? How did you install these? Why such old version of RPostgreSQL?