# Connecting to Azure database for PostgreSQL from R

Tags: r, postgresql, azure, ssl

I created a PostgreSQL server on Azure, but I am not able to connect to it from R. I am able to connect to it using pgadmin though

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user='xxx@azure-postgres', password='xxxxx', 
             dbname='dbname=postgres',
             host='azure-postgres.postgres.database.azure.com', 
             port = '5432')
```

If I have `SSL Enabled` in Azure, I am getting the following error in R `FATAL:  SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry`

I tried various variations to the parameters for dBConnect: `'dbname=postgres sslmode = allow'` but did not help. I got the same error. When I use `'dbname=postgres ssl = true'` R session crashed.

I have currently disabled SSL in Azure for now, and it is working. Is there any other option that I have.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try adding `sslmode=require` as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179039 ?

Comment: `sslmode=require` didn't work.