# How to require SSL in RMySQL in R?

Tags: r, ssl, dbi, rmysql

I used to connect to MySQL databases from R with this function:

```
db <- DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                            user = server$db_user,
                            password = server$db_pw,
                            host = server$host,
                            dbname = db_name)
```

This function works perfectly fine before. Now after we modified the databases with SSL, it is no longer working. What would be the solution to there?

Comment: Try specifying the `sslmode` like in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179039/4421870

Comment: Are you getting any specific error?